# How can I add an additional column to a database view in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have created a new view in my MariaDB database using phpMyAdmin combining the `#_content` and `#content_frontpage` tables called `#__content_with_featured`.

I am now attempting to add a new column to this view. Ultimately, it will contain calculated data based on other values from columns in the view, but at this stage I can't even add the column. I get an error referencing the second line:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `ADD #_content_with_featured.f_current' at line 2`

I have tried it with and without the view name. This is my SQL with the full new column name:

1. `ALTER VIEW #_content_with_featured AS`
2. `ADD #_content_with_featured.f_current`

What am I missing or doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW rather than ALTER VIEW, like this:

```
#_content_with_featured_two AS 
SELECT #_content.id AS f_id,
       #_content.title,
       #_content.featured,
       #_content.images,
       #_content_frontpage.featured_up,
       #_content_frontpage.featured_down,
       CASE
           WHEN #_content.featured = '0' THEN 'No'
           WHEN #_content.featured = '1' THEN 'Yes'
       END AS f_current
FROM #_content
LEFT JOIN #_content_frontpage ON #_content.id = #_content_frontpage.content_id
```

Note: the actual CASE query isn't what I'm trying to achieve, that's there for demo purposes only.